# Sqoop execution in HDInsight with curl is not working

Tags: curl, sqoop

The select query we are giving in the parameter '–query' is failing .

Command
curl -u : -d user.name= -d command="import --connect jdbc:sqlserver://:1433;database= --username  --password  --query \\"select\*\\from\\MEDICAL_DEP_EMPS\\" --append --target-dir adl://.azuredatalakestore.net//sheriff/testnewrdbmstoadld --temporary-rootdir adl://.azuredatalakestore.net//sheriff/testnewrdbmstoadld/temp --as-textfile --enclosed-by ' --escaped-by / --null-string \\N --null-non-string \\N --fields-terminated-by , --optionally-enclosed-by / -m 1 " -d statusdir="adl://.azuredatalakestore.net/tmp/dataingestion/3802/statusdirec1" https://qa-spark-cluster.azurehdinsight.net/templeton/v1/sqoop

Logs :
19/12/12 15:11:36 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.6.5.3009-43
19/12/12 15:11:36 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
19/12/12 15:11:36 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
19/12/12 15:11:36 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
19/12/12 15:11:36 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Query [\"select\*\from\MEDICAL_DEP_EMPS\"] must contain '$CONDITIONS' in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue with HDInsight and Azure PG confirmed .

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop --query option is expecting you to pass the $CONDITIONS in the free form select query.

You can refer to "7.2.2. Selecting the Data to Import" and "7.2.3. Free-form Query Imports" in [SqoopUserGuide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html)

Although below link is not "curl for sqoop import", i hope it will help you.

[submit-apache-sqoop-jobs-by-using-curl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-use-sqoop-curl#submit-apache-sqoop-jobs-by-using-curl)

Examples:
When using a single mapper, the entire selected data will be transferred sequentially by the one mapper.

```
 --query 'SELECT * FROM a WHERE $CONDITIONS' -m 1
```

If double-quotes are used need to add \ to avoid substitutions.

```
 --query "SELECT * FROM a WHERE \$CONDITIONS" -m 1
```

When using multiple mappers, selected data will be transferred parallelly by all the mappers after splitting based on the --split-by clause and substituting in place of $CONDITIONS.

```
 --query 'SELECT * FROM a WHERE $CONDITIONS' -m 3 --split-by a.column
```

Comment: Yes . I tried all the case .But the issue , HDInsight does not recognize the sqoop command when I incluse --query . In Culr to HDInsight we will give the sqoop command with "command= "<import sqoop command> . The same sqoop is working in Cloudra/Hortonwork .

Comment: Try using --table option in import command if you are actually selecting all columns from the table. You may use a combination of --table and --columns option as well for specific columns.